# Base Elements FileMaker Server is not reading files

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to read files from a mapped drive from filmmaker server 19 using base elements.
The script I am using works fine from console. when I run from the server I get a successful message but nothing actually happens.

Comment: post a sample of your code

Answer (score 0):

Try the BE custom function “BE_FileExists ( path )” first.
The best way to check a path and a file on the server is to launch a script on the server (PSOS) from a filemaker client that has 2 instruction:

1. BE_FileExists ( path )
2. returns BE_GetLastError to the client

Then you can debug the script result from the client.

By the way, the most common problem on a mapped external drive is that the filemaker server user needs first to mount the drive via BE_executeSystemCommand (even if the drive is already mapped by the rdp/ server user, filemaker server makes its own environment that doesn't know your external drive, so you need to mount it).

In my scripts that needs to access to external drive, I make these 3 steps:

1. mount the drive ( net use {drive_letter}: \{drive address} )
2. read/write data on external resource
3. unmount the drive ( net use /DELETE {drive_letter}: )